# Up to Date Node.js Beginners Tutorials

Tags: node.js

Where can I find some tutorials to begin learning Node.js? I've seen a few, but they are for the 0.4.x version, and, as I understand it, Node is on 0.6.x now. I searched Google and found a similar question on StackOverflow, but it was asked a good amount of time ago.

Comment: There is no much difference that you will notice at the beginning.

Comment: Most of the tutorials from 0.4.x still apply to 0.6.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on this on google, I wrote a beginners guide include step by step best places on the web to learn and in which order: https://medium.com/node-js-tips-tricks/e8baa5207c11

I am told it is useful, may it be for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this, were very useful for me when I started, good tutorials and the API reference got very good examples!
[nodemanual.org](http://nodemanual.org/latest/nodejs_dev_guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Learning from screencasts or CBTs is best way than going through manuals at beginning: [Node Tuts](http://nodetuts.com/) has wide range of video tutorials to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://www.nodebeginner.org/) got me up and running really quickly

Answer (score 0):

The DailyJs site has really good tutorials for building a practical web app with Node.js, Express, Jade, Backbone.

Source code is in github https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad

Tutorials here http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#lmawa

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this now you can go to [NODESCHOOL](http://nodeschool.io/).

They have some really good (up to date) lessons that should be able to get you up and running in no time.